# SharePoint remove site redirect through Graph PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, graph

is it possible to delete a SharePoint site redirect through the Graph PowerShell SDK? I recently changed the SharePoint site URL of an existing MS365 group and now the old URL (e.g. https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/GroupA) acts as a redirect to the new SharePoint site URL (e.g. https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/GroupB). Since I want to reuse the old URL, I need to delete the redirect first.

The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-redirects) state that this is possible through the SharePoint Online Management Shell. Unfortunately the Shell requires a Windows-based machine, which I cannot use. Therefore, I am trying to do this via the Graph PowerShell SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft does not seem to offer any functionality to delete SharePoint sites via the MS Graph API

The [Sites API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0) shows that MS Graph is only capable of deleting a permission object on a site rather than a site itself.

As MS Graph API doesn't expose any endpoint to delete sites, it will not be possible with the Graph Powershell module either.

It's unfortunate that the SharePoint Online Management Shell doesn't support Powershell core and that the SharePoint admin center offers no ability to delete these site redirects.

If you're not able to use a Windows machine to achieve this, I suspect a support call to Microsoft may be your only other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As NiMux mentioned,  it's not possible to delete SharePoint sites resp. site redirects via the MS Graph API. But another alternative is the [PnP PowerShell module](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/index.html), which among other things provides several SharePoint Online cmdlets. I was able to remove the redirect with the cmdlet [Remove-PnPTenantSite](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Remove-PnPTenantSite.html#example-1).

The module is open-source, community-developed, [officially recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets#supportability-and-sla-for-pnp-powershell-cmdlets) and cross-platform which means it works on an Azure Ubuntu VM (tested it myself).